# Azure free usage limits

Tags: mysql, azure

I signed up for the Azure free trial now, I do not know how it works. I would like to know what limits of use I will have after the free plan ends. I have a site with 400mb and 10mb of MySQL database, can I host for free without exceeding the limits of using the free plan?

Comment: This is site is ENGLISH only. Or how many other questions did you notice that are written in Spain(?). Please translate your question or delete it, no middle ground. And please please please: spend some time at the [help] to learn how/what to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

When 30 days have passed, you can continue using your free products after you upgrade your account to Pay-As-You-Go Azure subscription and remove the spending limit. As long as you utilize the service quantities included for free, you will not have to pay anything.

For more information refer the below documentation:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/free/free-account-faq/

Comment: That's all about old products and it's obsolete. Now there are products with limits based on hours of use (750 hours), 1 year of use, a number of transactions, a storage limit... Or a mix of all. It's not so easy since you can be charged at any time even if using "free" products.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with this "free" tier (both AWS and Azure) is that you must be always checking if you shut on/off your services, and if you fail one day, or if you are sleeping, on holiday, travelling, if your latpot just gets out of battery... A simple DDOS attack or the fact of reaching the limit just in the moment can generate for you costs for +400$ in a few days. Microsoft and AWS support must be really tired of checking tickets about that undesired costs, defaults, etc, etc, you ALWAYS are suitable for getting charges, the name "free" is a false friend.

A trick that works for me is registering a credit card for payment and then cancelling it, so if undesired costs are generated, they can not just get the money. It worked for me, I talked with support and they cancelled costs in about 2 weeks, and no money were taked from my account.